# I have made a program to implement stack but it is not working properly

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

The code is not throwing any error but it is not taking the values that we pass in the enqueue function.
Here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

struct Queue{
    int *arr;
    int front , rear;
    int cap;
    Queue(int c){
        cap = c;
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
        arr = new int[cap];
    }
    void enqueue(int x){
        if(rear == cap-1){
            cout<<"The array is full";
        }
        rear++;
        arr[rear] == x;
        cout<<arr[rear]<<endl;
    
        if(front == -1){
            front = 0;
        }
    }
    int dequeue(){
        int data;

        if(front == -1){`your text`
            cout<<"Array is empty";
            return INT_MIN;
        }
    

        data = arr[front];
        arr[front] = 0;
    
        if(front == rear){
            front = rear = -1;
        }
        else{
            front++;
        }
        return data;
    }
};
int main() {
    Queue q(3);

    q.enqueue(24);
    q.enqueue(30);
    q.enqueue(42);

    cout<<q.dequeue();
    return 0;
}
```

the enqueue function is taking some garbage value instead of the integer value that we are passing in the argument.

Comment: Move to this line `arr[rear] == x;` and think about it again.

Comment: Unrelated : remove  `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` it is not standard C++. And stop using `using namespace std;`  replace new int[] with std::vector<int> (in C++ try to avoid manual new/delete), or use std::make_unique to avoid memory leaks (you have them now)

Comment: In addition to what has been said above: Looking at `new int[cap]`, I have to ask: where is your `delete[]`?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Don't ignore warnings https://godbolt.org/z/W9cKa83er

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you ignored your compiler warnings. Under https://godbolt.org/z/Pn1Mf115T i have thrown your code in an online compiler and it tells me/you:

```
<source>:20:19: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
        arr[rear] == x;
        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
<source>:20:19: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
        arr[rear] == x;
                  ^~
                  =
1 warning generated.
Compiler returned: 0
```

So the compiler tells you that you comparing instead of assigning the values. Thats the reason why your queue `takes garbage values`, it just never gets data assigned and the output is the uninitialized memory from your C-style array.

Rule of thumb: Do not ignore compiler warnings.